# Import multiple vCard files to Galaxy S3 contacts

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, contacts, samsung-galaxy-s-3, import

How can I import contacts from hundreds of vCard files to my Galaxy S3 which is shipped with Ice Cream Sandwich ? **I don't want to import it one by one.**

I am using Windows 7 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine all you vcard files into one. Exact process depends on operating system of your computer.

You can find some examples in http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/y2670pyopew